# How to modify XML attribute value using xml.modify when there are nodes with aliased namespace

Tags: xml

How to modify XML attribute value using `xml.modify` when there are nodes with aliased namespace

For example the XML is:

```
<ar:archive xmlns:d="http://guidewire.com/cc/p04_00406_a09_01855_00558/domain" 
            xmlns:o="http://guidewire.com/cc/p04_00406_a09_01855_00558/other" 
            xmlns:ar="http://guidewire.com/archiving" 
            xmlns:i="http://guidewire.com/importing" 
            platform-major="4" platform-minor="406" 
            application-major="9" application-minor="1855" extension="558" 
            importing-schema-version="2.0" archving-schema-version="1.0" 
            root-ref="root" archive-date="2012-10-04T02:02:30.44-05:00">
   <d:Company id="d55" FaxPhone="1234567890" /> 
</ar:archive>
```

And I would like to modify the value of `FaxPhone` to `1234`

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow: if you post code, XML or data samples, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Comment: Also: what language / environment / system do you want to do this in? Your question is not very clear....

Answer (score 0):

The `xml.modify` seems to indicate you might be using SQL Server for this - correct??

If so - use this code to achieve what you're looking for:

```
// define XML namespace aliases for the two relevant namespaces
;WITH XMLNAMESPACES('http://guidewire.com/cc/p04_00406_a09_01855_00558/domain' AS d, 
                    'http://guidewire.com/archiving' AS ar)
UPDATE 
    dbo.YourTableNameHere
SET 
    YourXmlColumn.modify('replace value of (ar:archive/d:Company/@FaxPhone)[1] with "1234"')
WHERE 
    (some condition here to find the right row in the table ...)
```